# Provide environment variables to Laravel Queue Worker on Amazon Beanstalk

Tags: php, linux, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I have this weird issue with mail notifications. I have deployment on **Amazon Elastic Beanstalk**, and I am using **Amazon SQS** as queueing service. For mail I am using **Mailgun**. Now the problem is when the mail notification is queued and processed it fails.

And here is the interesting part, when I send an email notification that is not queued, it is sent correctly, and after that the queue emails are sent as well for sometime and then again they start to fail.

I've added `SerializeModels` trait to notifications as well. However it does not work until I send one email that is not queued.

My `User` class has also properly implemented the method `routeNotificationForMail` and is returning the user's email.

Anyone faced similar issue?

**##EDIT**

So I have drilled it down to where the problem is, the worker process running in `systemd` is somehow unable to translate or transfer the environment variables from file `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env`. Now when I run this in terminal the queue is processing just fine. But when the queue worker is restarted nothing works.

I am using the `EnvironmentFile=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env` in my `laravel_worker.service`

Does anyone have any idea how I can go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trail and error... banging my head here and there... the solution was pretty simple.

I knew the command to supply environment variables to `tinker`, so I created a shell script with the following content.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/html && export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env) && php artisan queue:work
```

> The script file was owned by the root user, so I don't have to use `sudo` with `cat`

Then I executed the script through `systemd` service.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nohup /var/www/html/worker_script.sh
```

Through `.ebextenstions`

```
files:
    /var/www/html/worker_script.sh:
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/sh
            cd /var/www/html && export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env) && php artisan queue:work


    /etc/systemd/system/laravel_worker.service:
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            # Laravel queue worker using systemd
            # ----------------------------------
            #
            # /lib/systemd/system/queue.service
            #
            # run this command to enable service:
            # systemctl enable queue.service

            [Unit]
            Description=Laravel queue worker

            [Service]
            EnvironmentFile=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env
            Restart=always
            ExecStart=/usr/bin/nohup /var/www/html/worker_script.sh

            [Install]
            WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> All configuration files are available at https://github.com/stescacom/elastic_beanstalk_laravel_mongo_config Hope this helps someone else.